# Power BI: DAX formula - build sum on group ID

Tags: powerbi

I am just getting started with Power Bi and now I require some help.

I need a formula that creates a new column (called "Combined" in below example picture) that uses the following logic:

- build the **sum** of column **Current** over **each ParentID**
- if this sum is **> 0**
- then write the row value of Current in the Combined column cell
- else insert the **Budget** value instead

On the left side you see my current result and the desired output on the right.

[image: example]

I hope you can help me out.

**Update**:

To make the example a bit clearer, I combined both ParentIDs:
[image: ex2]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two calculated columns using the following measures:

```
Sum Of Current = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Current])
                 , FILTER('Table', 'Table'[ParentID] = EARLIER('Table'[ParentID])))

Combined = IF('Table'[Sum Of Current] > 0, 'Table'[Current], 'Table'[Budget])
```

If you are unfamiliar with creating calculated columns just right click on any column in your table and select the 'New Column' option:

[image]

If you don't need both columns just use this:

```
Combined = IF(CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Current])
           , FILTER('Table', 'Table'[ParentID] = EARLIER('Table'[ParentID]))) 
           > 0, 'Table'[Current], 'Table'[Budget])
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to adjust your last formula to my needs.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.